# Rails callback on data change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, rails-activerecord

I have 2 different applications working with one database. One of them is Rails application, only as user interface for displaying data.

So, I want somehow hook the moment, when another application made change in database, and perform Rail operation (i want to use websockets and send every listener this new data).

So, how I can handle this? If i changed model in Rails application, I could used ActiveRecord Hooks.

So, probably the good idea would be to run background worker, or something like this?

Or, may be the best idea would be ask server from javascript repetedly without websockets?

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer, if the second app(that modifies data in DB) would write something in message queue(Redis, RabbitMQ).

And your rails app will recieve this events and notify user.

The best transport between rails app and frontend - websockets. Use http://faye.jcoglan.com/ for example.

Answer (score 0):

The common thing is to use listners on certain ports. Here is few libs that could do the trick for you:

1. [Firehose](https://github.com/polleverywhere/firehose)
2. [Pusher](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-gem)

Basically all of them have same idea: send a note in `after_commit` callback to all clients that subscribed on certain port of your application.

Answer (score 0):

Well, thanks everybody for your answers, I think that I've found the best solution.

It uses new Rails4 feature - [SSE](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Live/SSE.html).

So, my controller's code is pretty easy and understandable:

```
class GaugeController < ApplicationController
include ActionController::Live

def index
    begin
        response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'
        sse = SSE.new(response.stream, retry: 300, event: 'message')
        loop do
            #get data from model to modelData
            sse.write(modelData)
            sleep(0.5)
        end
    ensure
        sse.close
    end
end
```

end

Maybe calling ActiveRecord half a second - too expensive, so probably i'll move to Redis.